# Accessing Promise.allSettled response property value. How?

Tags: javascript, deno

Since Deno brings javascript/typescript to desktop, I've decided to create a little tool to stress test the PHP-CGI gateway processing `.php` files for NGINX.

This worked fined for html static only sites but it seems a promise containing a fetch response of status `502: Gateway Timeout` is still considered `fulfilled` thus breaking the logic I've created. This is actually ok since NGINX is just telling you that PHP-CGI is down, not NGINX.

The response contains the value I need to create the logic I want but I can't seem to access it.

#### The code I am using:

```
/***
 *  ACME HTTP PHP Gateway Stress Tester 5000
 * 
 */
let promises: Promise<any>[] = [];
let fulfilled: number = 0;
let rejected: number = 0;

const requestCount: number = 1000;  // linear/procedural
const parallelCount: number = 100; // parallel/procedural

const fetchUrl: string = 'http://localhost/info.php';

// Fetch payload (GET)
// Null because url instead
const fetchPayload: any = null;

// Fetch options (GET)
const fetchOptions: any = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': '*/*'
  }
};

console.clear();

console.log(`
/***
 * ACME HTTP Stress Tester 5000
 * 
 * Stress test started... please wait.
 * 
 */
`)

let requestCounter: number = 0;

// Request counter...
for (let rc = 0; rc < requestCount; ++rc) {

  requestCounter++;

  // Parallel counter...
  for (let pc = 0; pc < parallelCount; ++pc) {
    // Push fetch calls into Promise array of promises
    promises.push(fetch(fetchUrl, fetchOptions));
  }

  // Execute fetch calls in Parallel
  await Promise.allSettled(promises).then((results) => {

    results.forEach((result) => {

      console.log(result.value); // <--- ERROR HERE

      if(result.status == 'fulfilled') fulfilled++; // Fulfilled counter
      if(result.status == 'rejected') rejected++;   // Rejected counter
    });

    // Debug output
    console.log(' Wave #         :', requestCounter);
    console.log(' Total Requests :', results.length);
    console.log(' Total Fulfilled:', fulfilled);
    console.log(' Total Rejected :', rejected);
    console.log('— — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — ')

    /***
     *  Reset these global vars on every new request
     *  containing 1,000 parallel fetch calls
     * 
     */
    promises  = [];
    fulfilled = 0;
    rejected  = 0;

  });

}

console.log(' Stress Test complete.');
```

#### The response I am getting:

Notice the 2 different `status` one `fulfilled` & one `502`. I need to access the `502` status.

```js
{
  status: "fulfilled",
  value: Response {
    body: ReadableStream {
      locked: false
    },
    bodyUsed: false,
    headers: Headers {
      connection: "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "10001",
      "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
      date: "Fri, 31 Dec 2021 05:53:39 GMT",
      etag: '"61bed520-2711"',
      "feature-policy": "autoplay 'none'; camera 'none'",
      "referrer-policy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
      server: "nginx",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
    },
    ok: false,
    redirected: false,
    status: 502,
    statusText: "Bad Gateway",
    url: "http://localhost/info.php"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output you show is from `console.log(result.value)` then note the structure of the data coming back. There are not two `status` fields there. One is `result.value.status: 'fulfilled'` and the other is `result.value.value.status: 502`.

It might be more clear if you break it into variables like this:

```js
results.forEach((result) => {
  // console.log(result.value); // <--- ERROR HERE
  const obj = result.value;
  console.log(`status is ${obj.status}`);
  console.log(`response status code is ${obj.value.status}`);

  if(obj.status == 'fulfilled') fulfilled++; // Fulfilled counter
  if(obj.status == 'rejected') rejected++;   // Rejected counter
});
```

Note that having the Promise fulfilled doesn't mean the API call worked. It means that you successfully got a response from your call.  The response itself might still have failed (in this case with a 502 error - bad gateway) but the Promise still fulfilled. If all you care to count is if the Promise fulfilled (resolved) or rejected, then what you have is correct.  But if you want to count whether the call it was making worked, then you should probably do something like this:

```js
results.forEach((result) => {
  
  if(result.status == 'fulfilled' && result.value.status == 200) {
    fulfilled++; // Fulfilled counter
    console.log(result.value.status);
  }
  if(result.status == 'fulfilled' && result.value.status == 502) {
    rejected++; // Rejected counter
    console.log(result.value.status);
  }
  if(result.status == 'rejected') {
    rejected++;   // Rejected counter
  }
  
});
```

Usually we care more about the actual result rather than how many promises resolved.

Comment: I was just thinking that MAYBE, it is not accessible until the response has fulfilled, which means... Maybe I should place the output inside the fulfilled if condition.... hmmmm.... testing.

Comment: You have one `.value` in there too much. There's only `result.status`, but no `result.value.value`

Comment: @Bergi no, that's my point. The output shows the result of `console.log(result.value);`, and that object contains another `value` too, so there really is `result.value.value`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This seems to be the case.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning But that output is wrong. `fetch` and `Promise.allSettled` don't produce a `.value.value`. Something else is going on here.